# Monitoramento em tempo real com localização

Tags: android, ajax, maps, geolocalização

Estou criando um app em "Android" em que eu possa localizar carros em movimento no mapa, qual seria a forma correta para enviar minha localização e monitorar os carros em movimento, qual api de maps eu devo utilizar?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, você precisa analisar se você precisa de uma informação em tempo real ou se pode haver um tempo de atualização.

Se você precisa da sua informação em tempo real, você pode utilizar o `Firebase` para isso. Com o `Firebase` você poderá ter informações em tempo real no seu client (Android) sem dificuldade. O problema é que, se você atingir um certo número de usuários/requisições, provavelmente você irá precisar adquirir algum plano (aqui tem uma tabela dos valores).

Mas, se sua plataforma permite uma atualização com um "delay", você pode criar um endpoint dentro de sua API, que receba e atualize as informações. Na parte do seu client (Android), você pode criar um `Service` para atualizar as informações com o servidor.

Para receber as informações de localização do aparelho, você pode dar uma olhada na documentação oficial.

**Links**:

- Planos e preços do `Firebase`: https://www.firebase.com/pricing.html
- Documentação Android do `Firebase`: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html
- Guia de como conseguir a localização do usuário:
  https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: Obrigado amigo, mas em relação ao mapa para que eu possa atualizar a localização dos carros no mapa a alguma técnica para que isso fique dinâmico, eu posso utilizar o Google Maps ou ele não dá suporte?

Comment: @BrunoRichart dentro do seu serviço, você pode armazenar as `LatLng` dos carros e mandar essa informação (através de um `Broadcast` ou `Eventos`) para sua tela do mapa. Para colocar as informações dos carros no mapa, você pode utilizar um `Marker` em forma de carro, e adicionar os novos carros com sua lista de `LatLng` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

Comment: Caso o carro mude de posição eu preciso que o mapa atualize a posição, mas não posso permitir que atualize toda a pagina, é possível mudar a posição de um Marker sem afetar todo o mapa?

Comment: @BrunoRichart sim!